# Jquery Multiple independent Ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table on by website with multiple rows of data. Each row of data can be edited on the row itself, and at the end of each row is a save button.

Hence if i have 10 rows, I will have 10 save buttons.

I want each save button to save the respective rows data to the database via an ajax call, and after the ajax call is complete, the button text changes to "saved". The thing is, the user may click on multiple save buttons in sequence without waiting for the previous save to complete.

Hence I need an ajax call that is unique to each button, however I'm having trouble finding an easy way to do this. Can someone help out with the ajax skeleton code? Do I submit the ajax call including the button ID and in the ajax complete function, I for the button id in the return ajax message?

Cheers
Kevin

Comment: The parent of each button will be the same row where your data lies. So you can just use the find() method to find all of the data, and the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you have a variable that knows the identity of the button that was clicked.  Lets call it `button`.

```
var button = // some button;
```

when you invoke your ajax call with logic such as the following ...

```
$.ajax({
    // Other parameters
    success: function(data) {
        $(button).text("saved");
    }
});
```

the instance of the `button` variable will still be in scope when the `success` callback occurs through JavaScript closure.  Thus the context of the callback is still known by the instance of that specific callback.

Here is a specific [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/L4a121bb/) that illustrates the solution using a table and buttons.  Instead of calling an Ajax service, I used the `setTimeout()` function to simply delay for a few seconds but the principle is the same.

Comment: Exactly the answer i was looking for!
$(this) no longer worked in the success call back. But it worked if i had previously assigned $(this) to a variable and then referenced that variable in the success callback.